# how to store multiple date values in custom field using salesforce FORMULA field date type

Tags: formula, formula-field, field-update

Hi i need to insert multiple Dates in custom filed.. using formula Only ...
how to insert the multiple dates like 1/1/2017;2/1/2017;3/1/2017 ... like that 
can you please give any suggestions to me... using formula datatype.

**EDIT:**

My requirement is I have 2 custom objects like Tracking_ticket__c and Old_register_Date__c. one object for Date Field, another for Formula date/Text field.

If we insert one date in Tracking_ticket__c custom field, that value is inserted in formula field, and another value is inserted in Tracking_ticket__c, updated and save next value in Old_register_Date__c.

Comment: You can't add multiple dates to a single date type field.

Comment: @ Martin Lezer, Thank you for respond, 
 So how it can be Update the Date.. But i need Old Date value also

Comment: Why don't you add different custom fields of type Date like: OlDate__c, CurrentDate__c,...

Comment: @ Martin Lezer, i add the custom fields also Tracking_ticket__c one field , another one is Old_register_Date__c formula filed.., 
 Once I change/ Update Tracking_ticket__c  the date value is inserted in Old_register_Date__c...

Comment: Please explain your whole requirement because we can't help you if we don't understand what you need.

Comment: @Martin Lezer, my requirement is i have 2 custom objects like Tracking_ticket__c and Old_register_Date__c. one object for Date Field, another for Formula date/Text  filed. if we insert one date in Tracking_ticket__c custom field, that value is inserted in formula field, and another value is inserted in Tracking_ticket__c updated and save next value in Old_register_Date__c.